# Double databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am just learning *`WPF (and mvvm)`*, and I have encountered a problem which I can't `google` through.

I have *`2 ObservableCollections`* - exercises and *charts (the project is about trackig progress in a gym)*:

Exercise (*Id, Name*)

Chart *(ExerciseId, ExerciseName, Id, ...)*

Now in a window where I want to fill the charts, I have a *`listbox`* with some *`labels`* and a `_grid`_ and a *`combobox`* in *`ItemTemplate`*.

`Listbox` is binded to Chart collection.
`Combobox` shows a list of exercises, so I am binding it to Exercise collection.

Questions:

1. Can I specify in xaml that combobox current value should be same as Chart.Exercise?
2. How can I specify a binding in XAML so Exercise collection element from a combobox would be assigned to Chart.Exercise?

Comment: How did you get on with this? Any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly achieve this with Element Binding and a Converter... However, it would be simpler to  achieve this in the ViewModel.

You would have four Properties in your ViewModel.

- Property 1: Exercise Observable Collection - Bound to your ComboBox ItemSource (ExerciseItems)
- Property 2: Exercise Selected Item - Bound to your Combobox SelectedItem         (ExerciseSelectedItem)
- Property 3: Chart Observable Collection - Bound to your ListBox    (ChartItems)
- Property 4: Chart Selected Item - Bound to your ListBox SelectedItem           (ChartSelectedItem)

You would Set your Combo Box Selected Item, using Linq perhaps, to be equal to the Item with ListBox Selected Item ExerciseID, in the Setter of the ListBox Selected Item Property;

```
Public Property ChartSelectedItem As ChartItem
Get
     Return _ChartSelectedItem
End Get
Set(value As ChartItem)
     If value <> _ChartSelectedItem Then
         _ChartSelectedItem = value

         ExcersiseSelectedItem = (From ExcersiseItemsList in ExcersiseItems Where ExcersiseItemsList.ID = value.ExcersiseID).FirstOrDefault

         OnPropertyChanged("ChartSelectedItem")

     End if
End Set
End Property
```

Hope that helps...